# How do you search for folders in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a large wordpress project inside Visual Studio Code and cant figure out how to search for specific folders. Say that I wanto to search for my plugin folder `my-plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I found is to use CMD P (or ctrl shift p) and write a part of the path (ie. you are looking for /first/second/third , write /third and you get the files inside the folder)